# Flying div into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/e6myD/1/).
I want when the `mousedown` event triggered on `#flyingDiv` I can move it around a `#holder`, when the `mouseup` and mouse goes away from `#holer` I can't move it. In my code sometimes `#flyingDiv` positioned near the black border when i move mouse in the center of `#holder`.
HTML:

```
<div id="holder" style="position: relative; margin: 20px auto; border: 1px solid black; width: 400px !important; height: 400px !important;">
    <div id="flyingDiv" style="position: absolute; background-color: green; width: 10px !important; height: 10px !important; left: 195px; top: 195px;"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    var fd = $("#flyingDiv");
    $("#flyingDiv").bind("mousedown", function(event) {
        $(this).attr("pressed", true);
    });
    $("#holder").bind("mouseup", function(event) {
        $("#flyingDiv").removeAttr("pressed");
    });
    $("#holder").bind("mousemove", function(event) {
        var div = $("#flyingDiv");
        if (div.attr("pressed")) {
            var width = div.width();
            if (event.offsetX >= width / 2 && ($(this).width() - event.offsetX) >= width / 2) {
                div.css("left", parseInt(event.offsetX - width / 2) + "px");
            }
            var height = div.height();
            if (event.offsetY >= height / 2 && ($(this).height() - event.offsetY) >= width / 2) {
                div.css("top", parseInt(event.offsetY - height / 2) + "px");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**UPD**
I found that if the `event.eventPhase == 3` it's old event. [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/e6myD/9/)
But still code works not fast.

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate the problem on Chrome, and this seems to be a performance problem; a mouse move event fires up very rapidly, and doing both DOM querying and writing on every event will choke a slower client at some points, in which the style won't get a value for top and left for a few frames, and it will default to 0.

You might want to look into premade, optimized solutions like [jQuery draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), since you're already using jQuery.

Comment: It's good `jQuery UI` function, but I wont to wrote own on Javascript and understand why my variant doesn't work. And I use `jQuery` just for easy appending attributes and css propertys and for easy community understanding, it's easy to replace my code by clear Javascript code. But I'm upvoting your answer and first try to use `jQuery UI`, thanks.

Comment: That's a good idea! You can start by browsing through the jQuery draggable source and see what's done differently. Remember that DOM query and writing are always slow actions.

Answer (score 1):

dont use bind, use $(element).mousedown().mouseup()

maybe something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/KQpe9/

```
    $(function() {
    $('.slider').slider();
});

$.fn.slider = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.css('top', 0);
        var dragging = false;
        var startY = 0;
        var startT = 0;
        $el.mousedown(function(ev) {
            dragging = true;
            startY = ev.clientY;
            startT = $el.css('top');
        });
        $(window).mousemove(function(ev) {
            if (dragging) {
                // calculate new top
                var newTop = parseInt(startT) + (ev.clientY - startY);

                //stay in parent
                var maxTop =  $el.parent().height()-$el.height();          
                newTop = newTop<0?0:newTop>maxTop?maxTop:newTop;
                $el.css('top', newTop );
            }
        }).mouseup(function() {
            dragging = false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: On your link there is only dragging by `Y` axis for me, but I need for both.

Comment: same way as you move Y you move X. few more lines of javascript.
http://jsfiddle.net/KQpe9/134/